# unable to run algo.louvain in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am kind of new to neo4j. I am trying to run the louvain algorithm in neo4j bolt using algo.louvain taken from https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-graph-algorithms/releases, on a Person(nodes) and KNOWS(relationship) data, but I get the following error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure `algo.louvain`: 
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.kernel.api.Statement.readOperations()Lorg/neo4j/kernel/api/ReadOperations;
```

Here is the query I am trying to run:

```
CALL algo.louvain(
'MATCH (p:Person) RETURN id(p) as id',
'MATCH (p1:Person)-[rel:KNOWS]->(p2:Person) RETURN id(p1) as source, id(p2) as target, count(*) as weight',
{graph:'cypher', iterations:5, write: true})
```

I am using neo4j 3.4.4 version, which is the latest. Is there a problem with query or is it some import issue? Has anyone faced a similar problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you taken the adequate version of graph-algo for your neo4j version (ie. the 3.4.0.0 ) ?

Comment: Yes that was the issue, thanks !